# Import CSV_file from desktop to R

Tags: r, csv, import

Hi I want to read in a CSV file into an R tibble using the function from 
the 'readr' package. Furthermore, I want to include the column names as well.
The CSV_file is on my computer desk.

I am totally new to it and have tried different things but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.csv("path/to/file/filename.csv")
```

Comment: df<-read.csv("C:\Users\hendr\Desktop\My files\Instagram.csv") 
I have tried but it tells me: Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"

Comment: @Sof look at your filepath using backslashes then look at my filepath using forward slashes.

Comment: Alternatively you can use double backslashes \\ instead of forward slashes

Comment: Yes, you can also use the normalizePath() function

Comment: data_test<-read_csv("C:/Users/hendr/Desktop/Files/Insta.csv")
Error: 'C:/Users/hendr/Desktop/Files/Insta.csv' does not exist

 (have you tried similar?)

Comment: Are you using RStudio ? Go to File then read from text import the csv. Copy the code in the bottom right panel it will look identical. Also use readr::read.csv()

Comment: Thank you so much! I have it now - but it just looks really odd, as the columns merge and therefore provides me with a tibble that contains 177 x 1 - can you somehow separate them so it looks like the original excel file

Comment: Change the delimiter argument provided to the sep parameter in read csv. It’s default is a comma your file may be separated by another delimiter such as a tab which is represented as \t

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really new to this and I really want to learn it - can you explain how I do it ? :-)

Comment: The function read.csv has many parameters which you can provide a range of arguments to, you can see these when you execute “?read.csv” in the console. One of those is the sep (separator) parameter which takes an argument that specifies the delimiter in your csv, and when evaluated by R it will be on those delimiters that your csv will be broken up into separate vectors (read columns).

Comment: @Sof please accept my answer and upvote it if you haven’t already.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to import `csv` in `R`. The most notable are:

- `read.csv`
- `read_csv` from `readr` if it's a standard `csv`. `read_delim` otherwise
- `fread` from `data.table` for all types of text files

`read.csv` is slow with respect to the two other functions because it does not automatically guess and optimize the column types, as the others do. So `read.csv`  is not the most desirable option.

`fread` is faster and requires less memory than `read_csv`. Both will give you a `data.frame` and an enhanced version of the `base R` dataframe: `data.table` for `fread`, `tbl_df` for `readr`